# Bootstrap 5: Dropdown auto close won't work

Tags: dropdown, bootstrap-5, auto-close

I have an issue about auto closing with bootstrap 5 (never tried with previous versions). I always have the default behaviour. I tried with Chromium and Safari (...).

To investigate, I started back, copying the code in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#auto-close-behavior, but the same default behaviour for all dropdown arises.

I checked that I have bootstrap.bundle.min.js loaded so it's not a problem of Popper import (other behaviors such as positionning are working anyway).

As an exemple, here is some complete code I have some issue with. It's a simple copy of the mentioned site.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="generator" content="Codeply">
        <title>Codeply simple HTML/CSS/JS preview</title>
        <base target="_self">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <style>/* build your own custom Bootstrap theme:
       https://themestr.app
    */</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="defaultDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Default dropdown
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="defaultDropdown" style="margin: 0px;">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuClickableOutside" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="inside" aria-expanded="false">
                Clickable outside
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuClickableOutside" style="margin: 0px;">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuClickableInside" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
                Clickable inside
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuClickableInside">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuClickable" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="false" aria-expanded="false">
                Manual close
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuClickable">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using beta(5.0.0-beta1) version of bootstrap 5. It is not stable version.

It is working fine with latest bootstrap version 5.1.3. Please use & try latest bootstrap version. check following.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="defaultDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Default dropdown
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="defaultDropdown" style="margin: 0px;">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuClickableOutside" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="inside" aria-expanded="false">
        Clickable outside
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuClickableOutside" style="margin: 0px;">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuClickableInside" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
        Clickable inside
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuClickableInside">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuClickable" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="false" aria-expanded="false">
        Manual close
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuClickable">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Interesting but intriguing behaviour. When run into snippet, behaviour is wrong but when run in full page, behaviour is right. Maybe some script that override the right behaviour...

Comment: Oh! It's auto-close!

Comment: The bootstrap samples don't function for me at all. I have to add ids, and targets, to get them to open and close, and the auto-open/close doesn't work. They only open and close on click of the menu button or the menu items.